# Mongoose Index not being Created before Query is Run

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When running my tests I'm getting an error stating I don't have a text index setup on the title field yet when running my application text searches work fine with this same model and don't throw the error.

> text index required for $text query (no such collection 'test-db.torrents')

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Category from './category';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Torrent = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    size: Number,
    details: [
        {
            type: String
        }
    ],
    swarm: {
        seeders: Number,
        leechers: Number
    },
    lastmod: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    imported: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    infoHash: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        index: true
    }
});

Torrent.index({
    title: 'text'
}, {
    background: false
});

export default mongoose.model('Torrent', Torrent);
```

I'm using [ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) for testing and here is my test case.

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import request from 'supertest';
import test from 'ava';
import {makeApp} from '../helpers';

test.before(() => {
    mongoose.Promise = Promise;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/astro-test-db');
});

test.after.always(() => {
    mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(() => {
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });
});

// Should return [] since HL3 doesn't exist.
test('should return no search results', async t => {
    const app = makeApp();
    const res = await request(app).get(`/api/search?q=HL3`);

    t.is(res.status, 200);
    t.is(res.body.error, {});
    t.is(res.body.torrents.length, 0);
});
```

Here's the full ouput from ava, as you can see the index for title doesn't get created with 'text' or `background: false`.

```js
➜  astro git:(develop) ✗ yarn ava test/routes/search.js -- --verbose
yarn ava v0.24.6
$ "/Users/xo/code/astro/node_modules/.bin/ava" test/routes/search.js --verbose

Mongoose: categories.ensureIndex({ title: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
Mongoose: torrents.ensureIndex({ category: 1 }, { background: true })
Mongoose: torrents.count({}, {})
Mongoose: categories.ensureIndex({ slug: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
Mongoose: torrents.find({ '$text': { '$search': 'x' } }, { limit: 100, sort: { score: { '$meta': 'textScore' }, 'swarm.seeders': -1 }, fields: { score: { '$meta': 'textScore' } } })
  ✖ should return no search results 

  1 test failed [13:59:07]

  should return no search results
  /Users/xo/code/astro/test/routes/search.js:24

   23:     t.is(res.status, 200);            
   24:     t.is(res.body.error, {});         
   25:     t.is(res.body.torrents.length, 0);

  Difference:

    - Object {
    -   code: 27,
    -   codeName: "IndexNotFound",
    -   errmsg: "text index required for $text query (no such collection \'astro-test-db.torrents\')",
    -   message: "text index required for $text query (no such collection \'astro-test-db.torrents\')",
    -   name: "MongoError",
    -   ok: 0,
    - }
    + Object {}

  _callee$ (test/routes/search.js:24:7)
  tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
  Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
  Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
  step (test/routes/search.js:19:191)

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Are you dropping your collections in the tests? There could be a case where the query starts execution before the index is created. What do you see with `mongoose.set("debug",true)` set before `mongoose.connect()` gets called?

Comment: The collections get dropped after all tests finish. I completely forgot about mongoose's debug mode. I'll check and come back.

Comment: After some testing it looks like mongoose adds `background: true` to index creation meaning the indexes are created after the tests finish.

Comment: Was already typing that in as you responded. It's actually default MongoDB behavior, so you need to set it to false as shown

Answer (score 5):

You should make sure the index is created in the "foreground" since "background" creation is default.

```js
Torrent.index({
    title: 'text'
},{ "background": false });
```

At least for your tests, otherwise there is a possibility that the query can run before the index is created. Setting `{ background: false }` makes sure the index is there before other operations can run. This is opposite to the [default behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options-for-all-index-types) of MongoDB, so it needs to be an explicit setting.

In production environments it is usually best to deploy indexes by other means anyway. Also "foreground" creation results in a smaller index size but of course "blocks" IO, but it's still generally better to do this at least once in production.

Citation from [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/build-indexes-in-the-background/)

> By default, MongoDB builds indexes in the foreground, which prevents all read and write operations to the database while the index builds. Also, no operation that requires a read or write lock on all databases (e.g. listDatabases) can occur during a foreground index build.

Which means no reads or writes can occur when this happens. So data cannot be inserted and queries cannot be run whilst indexes are being created when in "foreground" creation mode.

As for size, a little further down the same page from the citation:

> Background index builds take longer to complete and result in an index that is initially larger, or less compact, than an index built in the foreground. Over time, the compactness of indexes built in the background will approach foreground-built indexes.

So you can create indexes in the background that will *"over time"* come down to a more compact size in a production environment. But for **testing** and development purposes, your default should really always be to create in "foreground" in order not to be caught out with timing issues.

---

As a minimal test case:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.set('debug', true);

var testSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String }
});

testSchema.index({
  title: 'text'
},{ background: false });

var Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/texttest');

Test.create({ title: 'something here' },function(err,doc) {

  Test.find({ "$text": { "$search": "something" } },function(err,doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
   console.log(doc);

   Test.collection.drop(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
   });
  });
});
```

As an alternate approach, turn off mongooses autoindex feature automatically and set manually, then call creation manually via [`.ensureIndexes()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.ensureIndexes):

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.set('debug', true);

var testSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String }
},{ autoIndex: false });

testSchema.index({
  title: 'text'
},{ background: false });

var Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/texttest');

// Manually set indexing to on
Test.schema.options.autoIndex = true;
//console.log(Test.schema.options);

Test.ensureIndexes(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  Test.create({ title: 'something here' },function(err,doc) {

    Test.find({ "$text": { "$search": "something" } },function(err,doc) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(doc);

      Test.collection.drop(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        mongoose.disconnect();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't looks like this works, I'm still getting the same issue and there's no output from mongoose setting the index.

Comment: @AlexisTyler It works for me. Foreground index creation should block IO anyhow. There are more notes on foreground index creation in the documentation. I'm Just digging some up now.

Comment: @AlexisTyler Added a minimal case to at least reproduce. This will consistently create the index before the query can be run

Comment: @AlexisTyler Where's the data? I see no data inserted in your log output.

Comment: Okay I'm really tired but I'm guessing you're saying without any torrents added to the collection that the indexes are skipped?

Comment: @AlexisTyler I also see no index being created for text at all. You seem to be skipping a lot of detail here. That is what the "minimal test case" is for. You can compare what is done here to what you are doing and see where your differences are. In reality you "should" be creating indexes **before** your application or tests run anyway. Mongoose creating indexes on startup is really only a convenience for development purposes.

Comment: If you check the first section the index is being created with the model.

Comment: Okay after adding a torrent the indexes are created so I was correct.

Comment: @AlexisTyler Yes it's expected. I've given you a couple of samples. The point being that MongoDB does not create **anything** until there actually is some data. So no collection and no index either.